# Using ServiceLoader within an annotation processor

Tags: java, annotation-processing, serviceloader

Is it possible to use `ServiceLoader` from within the `init(ProcessingEnvironment)` method of an Annotation Processor?

```
 interface Service {}

 class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         ServiceLoader<Service> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Service.class);
         System.out.println("Found Services:");
         for (Service service : loader) {
             System.out.println(service);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment env) {
         super.init(env);

         ServiceLoader<Service> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Service.class);
         System.out.println("Found Services:");
         for (Service service : loader) {
             System.out.println(service);
         }
     }

     ...
 }
```

Running the main method produces the services I have specified in the META-INF/services file.  However, when the `init(ProcessingEnvironment)` method is called as part of a build of another project, it doesn't list any of the services.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Can you describe your setup a bit more? What projects do you have? Where are your services defined? The short answer, yes, it should be possible. But you should figure out why the META-INF/services file isn't on your classpath. What's the classpath when you run the main method?

Comment: I'm using Maven to handle all the dependencies between project so the classpath is a little magical right now.  I'll dig into that and see if I can come up with a better answer though.

Comment: Something else I found interesting, when I loaded the Processor service (as in, annotation processor) from within an annotation processor, I got an empty list as well.  And I know the classpath is setup correct there because I'm in an annotation processor!

Comment: A description of how your maven projects are setup and how you're running the main method would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is ServiceLoader uses `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` when a ClassLoader is not specified which cannot see the `META-INF\services` files from within an Annotation Processor but can from the `main` method.

Using `ServiceLoader.load(Service.class, AnnotationProcessor.class.getClassLoader())` properly loads the services from within AnnotationProcessor.

(Feel free to add to my answer if you know why ContextClassLoader cannot see `META-INF\services`)

Comment: Thanks you for the tip. Saved me hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to run your annotation processor with **Java module system**:

It seems to me that for Java 11 the `javac` compiler is not completely module-aware. I succeeded to properly setup `javac` for annotation processing by using `--module-path`, but loading a plug-in via `ServiceLoader` into my annotation processor in the same way turned out to be impossible. Thus after a very loooong time fiddling around with all possible kind of compiler options, I ended up in a hybrid way loading the processor via module path and loading the services via class path.

All in all, the following steps were required for me (I worked directly on the `javac` command line):

1. proper `module-info.java` setup with correct `uses` and `provided with`
   declarations for both, the annotation processor and the services to
   be loaded
2. load `ServiceLoader` via non-default `ClassLoader` (refer to bnorm's answer)
3. provide `META-INF/services` file for services to be loaded
4. specify path to services via `-classpath` (or `-processorpath`)

Comment: I use a maven project. And use java 9 and its module system. My annotation processor can not see my service. Even I use the processor's class loader, add a META-INF/services, add provide in the module-info. The apt work except can not find spi. If I load spi out of apt, it work. so just apt can not see the spi.